# Will JVM issue warning during runtime for using @deprecated codes?

Tags: java, deprecated

Will JVM issue warning during runtime for using @deprecated codes?

If it doesn't, can i make it warn for using @deprecated codes?

Comment: *"Will JVM issue warning during runtime for using @deprecated codes?"* Why not heed the warnings (update the code) at compile time?

Comment: I'm not an expert on AOP, but you may be able to use AspectJ to inject log messages at each invocation of a `@Deprecated` method / class / ... This would mean writing some kind of a 'wrapper' around your main class... I'm not putting this as an 'answer' because I don't actually know if it would work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will JVM issue warning during runtime for using @deprecated codes?

No.

> If it doesn't, can i make it warn for using @deprecated codes?

Not any way that I know of.

---

OTOH it is possible to find out in code, at runtime, if a particular member is deprecated:

```
import java.awt.Panel;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;

class TestAnnotations {

    @Deprecated
    public Object getStuff() {
        return null;
    }

    public static void showAnnotations(
        Object obj,
        String methodName) throws Exception {

        Class cls = obj.getClass();
        Method m = cls.getMethod(methodName);
        System.out.println(m);
        Annotation[] as = m.getDeclaredAnnotations();
        for (Annotation a : as) {
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Panel p = new Panel();
        showAnnotations(p, "show");

        TestAnnotations ta = new TestAnnotations();
        showAnnotations(ta, "getStuff");
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
public void java.awt.Component.show()
@java.lang.Deprecated()
public java.lang.Object TestAnnotations.getStuff()
@java.lang.Deprecated()
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: AFAIK @deprecated flags are stripped by the compiler. The JVM doesn't know anything about it. As with generics, they are stripped at compile time too, so there is no way to tell if it has been hit or not.

Comment: @Florian I don't think Deprecated flags are stripped by the compiler.  The [Deprecated annotation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Deprecated.html) has a retention policy of runtime.  And the JVM spec says that there is a [Deprecated attribute](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html#78232) in class files (maybe the annotations are converted into class file attributes however).

Comment: It seems the Class file still contains the information. But I don't think it's advisable to read that... I think that was reserved for the JVM. Anyways, it seems you can actually get to it with reflection. I admit, @AndrewThompson, you surprised me. Didn't know that something like this would work. Good job.

Comment: The "deprecated" flag is set from the @Deprecated annotation *or* by other means in the case of classes compiled from pre-Java 5 source code.

Answer (score 2):

> Will JVM issue warning during runtime for using @deprecated codes?

No it won't warn you.

> If it doesn't, can i make it warn for using @deprecated codes?

In practice, no.

I guess it is theoretically possible to make the VVM do this by implementing your own class loader and parsing the class files by hand to extract and check the "deprecated" attributes of all of the methods used.  However, that would be an awful lot of work because you'd need to replicate a large part of the parsing and checking logic that happens under the hood in a normal classloader.  It would also (I think) require you to modify the JVM's bootclasspath to get your classloader to be used for everything.  So even if this is possible, it is a really bad idea.

---

@prunge's comment suggests an alternative which would be simpler to implement ... and more "kosher" ... but still not an easy task.

Comment: You could use the [instrumentation API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) and write an agent that has a ClassFileTransformer.  It wouldn't be trivial to do so, however.

Answer (score 1):

No and you shouldn't do that. There is nothing wrong with `@Deprecated` code. This is simply a hint from the library provider that the code/method/class is no longer the recommended way of doing something and may fall out of service life. Most open source projects will have a defined rule for the schedule by which code may be marked deprecated and then removed. I've typically seen 1 major release for deprecation and removal in the subsequent major release.

Answer (score 0):

The proper thing to do is heed the deprecation warnings that are emitted when you compile the code.  They're there for a reason.  Most times, you can pretty easily find out how to update the code by reading the fine manual, and then you don't have to worry about running deprecated code at all.

Answer (score 0):

No,  annotations are not available at runtime (no such information will be embedded into bytecode)

they are just instructions to compiler. The compiler gives warning to the programmer (if it is not suppressed) that better implementations exist & don't use methods that are deprecated (ie marked @deprecated)

Comment: @Deprecated information *is* embedded in the bytecode. It is used for compilation information (eg when compiling against external jars that contain deprecated methods) and you can access it through reflection.